# Trigger multiple jQuery scripts on current active element

Tags: javascript, jquery, element, toggleclass

I'm a bit new to jQuery and I have difficulties in achieving a function so I really hope somebody could guide me a bit. What I basically want to do is to highlight 2 elements simultaneously (via toggleClass).

Basically I have a repeating div (`#post`) which contains a title, thumb and description div. What I would like to do is once I hover on the title or the thumb div the elements to get a new additional class (`xxxHover`). So basically once the user hovers the mouse on the title/thumb div the title/thumb div (both of them) get a new class called (`xxxHover` where xxx stands for the div name - in this case titleHover/thumbHover).

I might not be the best in explaining so I've prepared a jsFiddle as well:

http://jsfiddle.net/yLqnd/12/

As you can see my problem is to restrict the scripts for the current element only (#post in our case). If it helps or matter I have to say that this will be integrated into a WordPress website (so the HTML structure is basically in the loop.php), that's why I would like to restrict the 2x highlight effect only per item (#post).

Thanks a mill in advance for any idea!

Comment: Why don't you just use `.post:hover`?

Comment: Thanks guys for the quick help. Much appreciated! I have used Oscar's version with .parentNode. All of the answers are much appreciated and thanks for the quick feedback. Some of them are really good and elegant but won't apply in my case since I made a small mistake (I could say) in the description. The hover effects are different (in my example both turned to blue but it was just a plain example). Anyhow, cheers for all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/oscarj24/yLqnd/13/

Comment: Thanks Oscar! adding .parentNode after "this" made the trick!

Answer (score 0):

Here's an updated jsFiddle:
Instead of being so specific, any div's inside will now toggle the class

[jsFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/Bvss6/)

Basically I pushed it all together:

```
$(".post div").mouseover(function(){  
    $(this).closest('.post').find('div').toggleClass('thumbHover');
}).mouseout(function(){    
    $(this).closest('.post').find('div').toggleClass('thumbHover');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can get the effect you're looking for by using .siblings() in jQuery.

```
$(".title").mouseover(function(){    
    $(this).toggleClass("titleHover");
    $(this).siblings(".thumb").toggleClass("thumbHover");
});
```

This will limit the toggleClass to only the .thumb that resides in the same .post.

http://api.jquery.com/siblings/

Answer (score 0):

simples, just do it on the parent of both elements:

```
$(".post").mouseover(function(){  
    $(this).find('div').toggleClass('thumbHover');
}).mouseout(function(){    
    $(this).find('div').toggleClass('thumbHover');
});
```